# Notification for down-vote/vote to close on your posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, down-votes, notifications

Sometimes users post questions or answers, and people vote down or close them without the user being notified. He should review his question and what it's unwelcome in the community giving him the option to delete it, because once it's closed, it can only be deleted in two days.

So I would like to ask to get notifications (in the notification bar) whenever I have a down-vote or a vote-to-close on my questions, so I can react quickly and improve/delete my post.

Answer (score 8):

Users should be monitoring their questions any way. For example, they should be still working on the problem and editing in any new information they have.

If they are doing it properly they'll notice the down votes or close votes and do something about it.

If they've just abandoned the question, well what does it matter if it gets closed?

Comment: The thing is many times users cast votes because they didnt understand something in the q or if the asker misdetailed something, as soon as he will get notified he will come in to check the problem and correct it, or else chances are more ppl are going to cast downvotes for the same thing over & over

Comment: @Shimmy If the question is that hard to understand, then the downvotes will be a good indication that it might be a good idea to clean it.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, so at least delete it before it's closed

Comment: Users without close voting rights can see close votes on their own question?

Comment: @Wesley - not sure on that, but they'd see "possible duplicate" comments though.

Comment: If you pose a question in the hope that someone else can find a solution, where you have not succeeded, there is no reason to come back every few hours to see if someone posted (you will be notified). I have had a question closed, without comment, by a moderator and did not find out until someone else commented on the fact 10 days later. I did not come back, because there were no new answers and I had no new information about the Q, which IMHO perfectly valid behaviour. I only will be working on the problem if I have new ideas, and only update the question with new info, if I have that.

Answer (score 2):

We are not going to be adding a notification for vote-to-close or downvotes.

However, there is now a [notification for question authors and followers that is sent when the question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation). Hopefully that can be used as a prompt for the author to review the question and see if edits can be made that can lead to the question being reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Notified how? By the inbox? Then they should also notice that their rep. is lowering, and normally at least one of the down-voters will comment as to why. If it is a case where the question needs to be closed, then generally there are comments for duplicates which show up there anyway too.

I don't really see how you could notify someone which would not be redundant for some feature already available in the site.

Comment: No, by the notifications. So if I subscribe to RSS for notification, or I use Chrome extension, I see it there and I know I have to help ppl to help me