# When did the rep notification for downvotes disappear?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, notifications, top-bar

I recently asked a meta question which is getting lots of downvotes (too bad it's not Winterbash anymore, would have been good for a few hats).

However, I am not getting the nice little -2/-4/-6 reputation notifications I used to get for downvotes.

This may have gone away a long time ago, but I remember getting those notifications for downvotes.

Searching meta hasn't resulted in anything on this, so my question is when the notification for downvotes went away? Was this a public announcement somewhere?

Comment: It didn't exist in 2011 when [this FR](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105431/notification-for-down-vote-vote-to-close-on-your-posts) was made...

Comment: We get notifications for those? O_O I didn't even know this.

Comment: Are you talking about your detailed reputation history or about top-bar notifications? Because to my knowledge the latter never showed negative changes. And [the former](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/193412/enderland?tab=reputation) does clearly show downvotes to me.

Comment: If you click on the "achievement" thingy, you should see them. As far as I recall it was when the new (not so new any more) top bar was rolled out. You don't get notifications for bad things, only for good things. (So you see a +8 when you get an upvote after a downvote, even on different sites, but no -2, ever.)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements).

Comment: Are you possibly conflating the -1 that appears when **you** downvote something? That certainly does appear in the achievements dropdown.

Answer (score 15):

It never disappeared because it never existed.

We never had notifications for downvotes.

The top bar achievements dialog is lighting up with a number only when there is a positive reputation change, it will never show -2, -4, -6 etc and it never did.

The only thing I can think of that might explain what you describe is that you installed a userscript that does show downvotes notifications, and the script stopped working for some reason.

Comment: "the only thing" <--- I could just be crazy, too ;-)

Comment: @enderland I have another idea. The reputation score in the top bar. I think that used to go down when a negative reputation effect occurred (downvote, unupvote, unaccept, user removed). That was as good as a notification. Nowadays, only positive reputation changes trigger an update of that.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought so too, but I can't find any documentation of that (???).

Comment: @enderland wait... [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9UAEp.png) brings up old memories... lost in the past... did it show negative changes as well? For the life of me, I can't remember! :/

Comment: Yes, the dropdown also showed negative changes.

Comment: It does show the math, so long as your total rep change is positive. If you're +3/-3, it will show you as +24. You can infer downvotes this way. However, if your total change drops below zero, it will disappear from the notifications. Also, this is aggregate of all posts on the site, not just your recent one, so a stray vote on an old post can give you the wrong first impression. Long story short, it's not a perfect representation. If you really want to see all the ways your rep has changed, then you'll have to click through to your reputation tab.

Comment: @frеdsbend all is correct. But I can't see anything I should change in the answer, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting you change the answer. Just trying to provide nuance for any future readers on what's actually being displayed.