# Why did I not see that I was downvoted in my achievements?

Tags: bug, down-votes, notifications, achievements-dialog

I logged on today, and saw nothing in my inbox or achievements bar, so I thought nothing happened. Upon looking on my profile just now, I saw that I was downvoted on [a previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309686/why-do-i-not-have-the-5-5-for-the-curious-badge).
Why did this downvote not appear as a notification in my achievements bar? Is this a bug?

Comment: Nope. It's just how it works. We don't show downvotes in the achievements dropdown.

Comment: @Catija I've seen them before, and if I click on it, I see "-2."

Comment: You'll see it if you check, but it won't turn on an alert. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272817/when-did-the-rep-notification-for-downvotes-disappear